# Vertical Text in Reporting Services (Bottom-Up)

Tags: textbox, reporting-services, vertical-text

I would like to display my text in a text box in Reporting Services vertically bottom-up.  I already can have it top-down by going to the WritingMode property of the text box and switching to 'tb-rl' but there is no option for bottom-up.

I have done some research and would really like to avoid creating an image and putting that into the text box...

Any thoughts?!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to do the same thing with vertical text bottom-up. Sadly 'tb-lr' isn't accepted as a valid value. I know you said you didn't want to create an image, but that appears to be the only solution. I ended up using the following to get the desired result.

[Bottom-up Vertical Text](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/ten-common-sql-server-reporting-services-challenges-and-solutions/#hr6)

Answer (score 11):

If you're using 2008 R2, you can choose Rotate270 under "WritingMode"